# MIUI Battery Saver запрос у пользователя контроль активности - без ограничения энергии

Tags: android, xamarin, gps, xamarin.android

В моем приложении используется несколько потоков с `GPS`, которые не должны прерываться, но после отключения экрана - `GPS` останавливается.

Чтобы `GPS` не останавливался нужно задать `"Контроль фоновой активности" - без ограничения`.

---

Я пробовал получить это так:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        String packageName = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName;
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);

        if (!pm.IsIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(Application.Context.PackageName))
        {
            intent.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations);
            intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + packageName));
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
```

Но это не дает нужного мне эффекта.

---

Как я могу задать данную настройку программно или хотя бы открыть её, чтобы пользователь сам выбрал `без ограничения` вместо `"умного" - адаптивного` ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, можно открыть это специфическое меню MIUI

Android:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322529/opening-miui-battery-saver-for-specific-apps

Xamarin:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.powerkeeper", "com.miui.powerkeeper.ui.HiddenAppsConfigActivity"));
intent.PutExtra("package_name", AppInfo.PackageName);
intent.PutExtra("package_label", Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name));
StartActivity(intent);
```